# Premiere mangles export of video with several settings

Tags: premiere

I am new to Premiere and tried a few sequences. Upon exporting them, the result has half the frames completely mangled, with unreadable text, inverted exposure, or with extraneous elements. Here are some examples:

[image: mangled export example 1]

[image: mangled export example 2]

[image: mangled export example 3]

The same result happens with different settings: medium or adaptive low bitrate, with hardware encoding or with software encoding. The same result happens with different sequences.

How can I fix the export and salvage my work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting in Premiere, I chose `Queue` in the Export dialog for Adobe Media Encoder to do the work. It worked perfectly fine, either with medium or high bitrate, with hardware or software encoding.

This issue may be due to new software running on old hardware. My computer has 8 GB of RAM. Although Premiere 2019-2020 has that amount as the minimum and so it should work, Adobe Support has [excused itself of another bug](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32904/premiere-pro-plays-media-video-stream-at-half-the-speed-as-audio) blaming the lack of the recommended RAM.